# How do I loop in Vertical Position?

Tags: java, loops

I’m a newbie at programming. I was ask to do a code where it prints a number in descending and in vertical position. Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main{
    public static void main (String args []){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int r=0,ascend=0;

        int number=input.nextInt();
        while(number>0) {
            r= number%10;
            number= number/10;
            ascend= (ascend*10)+r;
        }
        System.out.println(ascend + "\n");
        ascend++;
    }
}
```

However, when I put an input of: `214`

The output would be:

```
412
```

What can I do to turn the output like below?

```
4
1
2
```

Comment: Put `System.out.println(r);` in the while loop to print each digit on its own line as it is calculated. You can then eliminate the `ascend` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this.

It's basically the same as yours, with the print moved into the loop and printing each digit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int r = 0;

        int number = input.nextInt();
        while(number > 0) {
            r = number % 10;
            number /= 10; // assignment operator shorthand for number = number / 10;
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your println within the loop. With this, you can remove the `ascend` variable. With println, you also get the new line character for free

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r = 0;

    int number = input.nextInt();
    while (number > 0) {
        r = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        System.out.println(r);
    }
```